# Infinitivo flexionado ou simples a seguir à palavra "favor"

Tags: conjugações, concordância-verbal, infinitivo-pessoal

Em um email encaminhado a um grupo de pessoas, por exemplo, que iniciasse com "Prezados,"), quais das opções abaixo seria a correta:

1. > Prezados, favor solicitarem a alteração.

   solicitar flexionando com "Prezados".
2. > Prezados, favor solicitar a alteração.

   sugerindo a ação "favor solicitar" a cada receptor individualmente.

Comment: @bfavaretto Estas frases são estruturalmente diferentes das dessas perguntas. Parecem-me elipses de "É favor [vocês solicitarem a aliteração]" ou "É favor [solicitar a alteração]", portanto com a oração entre parênteses retos as servir de sujeito da oração matriz.

Comment: É verdade @Artefacto, vou retirar meu voto de fechamento.

Answer (score 1):

Estão ambas corretas.

Em primeiro lugar, *favor solicitar a alteração* é equivalente a ***é** favor solicitar a alteração*. *Solicitar a alteração* é aqui um sujeito oracional infinitivo de um predicador nominal (*favor*). A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (pág. 1926) dá os seguintes exemplos para este tipo de frases (a itálico está a oração infinitiva):

> a. É um sacrifício *os pais falarem com os filhos*.
>   b. É um privilégio (*nós*) *falarmos contigo*.
>   c. É uma alegria para mim (*tu*) *teres visitado a minha filha*.
>   d. É um sacrifício para nós *falarmos contigo*.
>   e. É um sacrifício para nós *falar contigo*.
>   f. É um sacrifício *falar contigo*.

Como se pode ver, quer o infinitivo flexionado, quer o simples podem ocorrer. A diferença entre as duas formas é apenas a interpretação do sujeito na oração infinitiva. Com o infinitivo flexionado, a referência é livre:

> É favor (*tu*) *solicitares* / *ele solicitar* / (*vós*) *solicitardes* / *eles solicitarem a alteração*.

Só não é possível *eu solicitar* e *nós solicitarmos* — seria estranho fazermos um pedido a nós mesmos, cf. [esta resposta do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-da-expressao-e-favor/18406).

Em relação ao infinitivo simples, o sujeito implícito da oração infinitiva (que não pode ser realizado) não pode nunca ser o beneficiário do favor pela mesma razão — mesmo que digamos *é um favor para nós*, tal como em *e.*, onde o sujeito da infinitiva é correferente com *nós*. O sujeito poderá então ter uma valor indefinido (aproximadamente igual a *é favor solicitar-se a alteração*) ou referir-se ao interlocutor (*é favor você solicitar/tu solicitares a alteração*).